# How to control another webpage on same window that i get after clicking link or a button on the previous webpage using .click() in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, browser-automation

I have a problem that i cannot interact with another webpage after i click the the button or link. The page does not open in a new tab. can I interact with it in the same tab.